# How to determine if fingerprint sensor can be used?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I'm working on an app that uses fingerprint as an authentication method. When the user tries to log-in the app displays a dialog and starts listening to the fingerprint sensor. The issue I'm having is that the sensor will be blocked by the system after 5 failed attempts, yet I can't find a way to determine when this happens. Nor can I find a way to determine when the sensor will be available again (usually this should happen after 30 seconds). Is there an API that I can use for this?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859211

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't found a straightforward api to do this, however I noticed that when calling `FingerprintManager.authenticate` and passing an instance of `FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback` I will receive an `onAuthenticationError` callback with a `onAuthenticationError` of 7 when the fingerprint sensor has been temporarily blocked. So I guess it's just a matter of handling those events and modelling my app to follow what the system allows me to do.